# Spring @Transactional method call by the method of another class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I just wanted to know what is the difference between if transactional method of class to  transactional/non transactional method of another class.

Option A:

```
@Service
class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    Addressdao addressDao;

    @Transactional
    void insert(Address address) {
        addressDao.insert(address);
    }

}

@Service
class AddressDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional
    void insert(Address address) {
        jdbcTemplate.insert(address);

    }
}
```

Option B:

@Service
class EmployeeService {

```
@Autowired
Addressdao addressDao;

@Transactional
void insert(Address address) {
    addressDao.insert(address);
}
```

}

@Service

```
class AddressDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    void insert(Address address) {
        jdbcTemplate.insert(address);

    }
}
```

Comment: In this case there is no difference.

Comment: If you dont annotate @Transactional annotation on insert method of AddressDao will proxy will be created for AddressDao ?

Comment: No there won't be. But functionally they will be the same as the outer transaction (the one on the service) is the effective transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum AFAIK, there is a difference: if the DAO throws a runtime exception, the transaction will be marked for rollback in the first case, and not in the second case.

Comment: They will be in both cases because in both cases there is already a transaction due to the `@Transactional` on the outer service. The exception isn't cached so that will see the same `RuntimeException` and rollback the tx.

Comment: In both case it will insert the data into table. If any exception is thrown after the insert statement of AddressDao the transaction is not rolled back and the data is inserting in both cases